# 3D cube model with picture in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, overlay, merge

I'm trying to merge down the picture layer on the sides of the cube, however, the results is that the image is merged down on the sides that I don't really intended. I'd like the picture to wrap the front sides of a cube that are actually visible.

How should I solve this?

Here are the pictures:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with merge? Do you want to add that circle as a texture on the cube? Why not use the 3D tool for that? What's the end result you want?

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/3d-painting-photoshop.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. My goal is make an optical illusion out of a cube so that the viewer would be able to see a circle from the specific viewing point (1st image). This means I need to overlay/merge the existing circle layer on top of the cube. Here's another image of the result: https://ibb.co/kKBPjx. Please note the differences in spaces between the horizontal lines   on the top side of the cube vs the left and right side of the cube - this actually helps create the illusion. However, some parts of the circle are missing, for some reason they are on the bottom of the cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you.

Select and unwrap the front.

Select the Front Merged Material Layer and Edit its texture.

Now you will see the results in the cube while you paint the the texture.

See images below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please look at my comment on top.

Comment: Apparently, in my case I needed to select Generate UVs and then Merge Down the circle layer with the cube. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want 2D images of the visible cube sides for making a real cube.

The projections of the circle on the sides of the cube are elliptical arcs. A competent person could calculate their radiuses and main axles. Making the projection with a 3D program is much easier than performing those calculations manually.

Even in simple freeware 3D programs you can project your circle + other details onto a cube from the wanted direction. See an example. At first the circular shape is constructed on a plane.

[image]

Unwanted parts are trimmed away and the plane is rotated to the wanted position relative to the cube. The pattern is projected onto the surface of the cube.

[image]

This can be enough for your purposes, if you do not need more 3D operations. Simply save the cube surfaces as 3D vector drawings.

I tried to etch the pattern into the cube. Here's 2 different projections of the result:

[image]

[image]

**ADD:**  Because straight lines are straight lines also in the projection, you do not have to draw all of them in a 3D program. Most of them can be inserted manually in a drawing program if you have 2D images of the projection of a circle and its diameters from 9 to 3 and 12 to 6 a'clock.

Here it is done and opened in illustrator:

[image]

The cube is seen in isometric projection and the center of the circle is aimed to the nearest corner of the cube.

Comment: The theory is right, the question is though how do you actually project the circle in practice? Since I'll have to print and build the actual cube with the corresponding optical illusion the flat vector image that you posted on the right is of special interest to me.

Comment: @user1860809 I can show how the flat Illustrator image was generated from scratch, if that's what you wanted. The work is elementary. You must draw all small details of the projected circular shape by yourself. It's surely easiest before the projection. Get that freeware 3D CAD program. It's DesignSpark Mechanical (=a heavily decimated version of SpaceClaim, but still useful). It has line drawing generation disabled, but you can print a PDF like I did. That's editable in Ai.